# Amanda: how to skip a tape?

Tags: amanda

I swapped out some tapes from our older Amanda system over the weekend. In doing so I was a bit over-eager and took out the first tape that Amanda was expecting to use for the weekly backup run. The next several tapes in the series are all present but now the run has been put in the holding disk.

How would I tell amanda to 'amflush' the backup run but skip to the next tape in the series? IE its expecting 'ARCHIVE-0150, ARCHIVE-0151, ARCHIVE-0152, ARCHIVE-0153, ARCHIVE-0154' and I want it to start with ARCHIVE-0151 and continue on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: edit the 'tapelist' and move the last entry ( the problematic tape ) to the top of the list and edit the date. Amanda will start with the last tape in the file and proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you removed the tape and discarded it, you need to tell Amanda that it and its contents no longer exist.  Use

```
amrmtape DailySet1 ARCHIVE-0150
```

to delete it from Amanda's tape database.

If you still have the tape and want Amanda to remember what it contained, use

```
amadmin DailySet1 no-reuse ARCHIVE-0150
```

Manually editing the tapelist file isn't a good habit but it can work in a pinch.  It's safer to use the administrative commands provided by Amanda.